# Control width of html block Gutenberg Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm placing html into my Gutenberg block in wordpress.  But how can I control the display width of the block?

```
<figure><iframe src="https://cstangor.shinyapps.io/shiny/"></iframe></figure>
```

I tried this: but it didn't seem to make a difference.

```
<figure><iframe src="https://cstangor.shinyapps.io/shiny/" width="“100%”" height="“1000”" frameborder="“0”" allowfullscreen="“allowfullscreen”"></iframe></figure>
```

Comment: Remove these `“ ”` quotations.

Answer (score 2):

You have twice of double quotes in attributes. Please remove that quotes `“` and `”` from attributes.

```
<figure>
    <iframe src="https://cstangor.shinyapps.io/shiny/" width="100%" height="1000" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
    </figure>
```